# using $driver->send_modifier() call with Perl Selenium::Remote::Drive package

Tags: perl

Has anyone had any luck using $driver->send_modifier()  call with Perl Selenium::Remote::Drive package?

I am trying to perform an operation with the "ALT + $key", example: Alt + x

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing issues with *send_modifier*, but a work around that i use for now is as follows.

```
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;
....
my $element = $driver->find_element_by_id('id_of_element_to_receive_alt_x');
$element->send_keys(KEYS->{'alt'}, 'x');
```

Hope this helps.